# My drawableLeft are disappearing "randomly"

Tags: android

This seems to be a question specific to the project I'm working on.

This project has seen several developers and haven't been coded properly on many points. I'm also new to Android developing, so I may be missing something really basic here.

We have a search page where we can search for `"posts"`, `"users"` and `"groups"` with one search field. The results are kept in a `StickyListHeadersListView`. If we touch the header of each result type, we access a sub-page showing more results for this type.

My problem is related to users cells. We have two buttons that we can touch to `follow/unfollow` this user, with a `drawableLeft` that changes when we press the button.

For each cell, only the corresponding button will be shown. Here is their code (with another id and drawableLeft for the second button):

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_follow"
    style="@style/Button.Small"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/button_follow"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    android:text="@string/follow" />
```

The drawableLeft code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:enterFadeDuration="100" android:exitFadeDuration="100">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_button_add_on" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_button_add_off" />

</selector>
```

The cell layout is used on other pages and works just fine there. On the search page, icons are here, but sometimes disappear quite randomly. Buttons should always have a `drawableLeft` visible, and there is none when this problem occurs, on all users in the list. I've got no error in `LogCat` either.

[Here is a screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xncn1xg2t5eduj6/Screenshot_2014-03-13-11-25-50.png) of my cells when they have no `drawableLeft`.

I've tested it on a Galaxy S2 and S3. I'm not sure of it but it seems to happen a lot when the request to the API is completed. One of my co-workers told me it could be a problem with the cursor, but I have no idea how to check that.

I'm sorry, this question is rather unclear, but maybe it will ring a bell to someone.

Thank you for your attention!

**Edit**
Added a link to a screenshot to explain better what my problem is.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "disappearing randomly"? If I understand your requirement correctly, the drawableLeft should be on if you are following a user, off if not. Your selector doesn't do that - instead, it just sets the button to "on" when you click on it, then returns to its original state. Maybe you need something like ToggleButton? If not, please be more clear on what the problem is.

Comment: Yes, buttons should always have a `drawableLeft`, though we have two buttons. The follow and unfollow buttons visibility is set to `GONE` depending on the current state. The problem is that sometimes, there is absolutely no `drawableLeft` displaying.

Comment: change <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_button_add_off" /> to
<item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_button_add_off" android:state_pressed="false" />

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't change anything, sadly :(